# How do you use Webstorm and Idea together?

Tags: java, javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm

I've recently started working on a project that uses a mix of javascript and java code.  We're using the community edition of IDEA for the java code and Webstorm for the javascript.

This would be fine except for the fact that they share the same .iml files and as a result end up interacting horribly with each other!  Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: *"Is there any way to stop this?"* -- use/purchase IntelliJ IDEA **Ultimate** (which supports everything) ?? Or separate JS into separate project -- so that .iml files do not intersect.

Comment: Another possible approach is to keep project settings (.idea subfolder) in another location (exact steps described in http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-343 ticket body).

Comment: @LazyOne nice one that seems to have done the trick.  If you want to post it as the answer I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things you could do:

1. Upgrade to IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate (paid product) which supports all these languages.
2. Separate JavaScript and Java code in different projects. Two options here:

a) Keep both projects in different folders (subfolders) so that *.iml and other config files do not intersect and do not interfere with each other.

b) Keep actual code as you have it now, but store project config files (`.idea` subfolder) separately -- just follow steps exactly as described in [WI-343](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-343) ticket body (create empty project elsewhere; remove default content root; add desired content root).

Comment: we might end up getting the full version of idea but have just had to pay out a load of money for various other licences.  hopefully if we stick with the cheap ones for the java + javascript we can get new VS + resharper licences!  I'm stuck on VS2010 + Resharper 6 unfortunately, although that still seems to be better than any other IDE I've tried